# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0 after installing core

Tags: asp.net-web-api

After installing ASP.NET web API 2.2 core I'm getting this problem. I'm using visual Studio 2013. I've seen a similar problem in stack but as my problem I can't solve it. If there is any way to solve it please let know.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyYS1.png).

Comment: use fuslogvw.exe to see where it's trying to load the dll's from, who is the originator of the load request, etc.  Helps figuring out why it's going wrong.

Comment: This happens where there is a mismatch between the dlls. Check your `Web.config` file  assembly binding and compare with the version which is referenced in the project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind consideration. The problem has solved. I have installed microsoft asp.net web api 2.2 client libraries.